# Cypress: run entire test suite multiple times with different data

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have seen several posts about running a single test with different parameters. It is also documented [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Dynamically-Generate-Tests).

However, I couldn't find any examples of how to run the entire test suite, i.e. tests across multiple files in the `cypress/integration` folder multiple times with different data.

My scenario is that I want to stub different responses from an API I'm calling and run all test cases against the different responses. So for the 1st run, I would put in `support/index.js`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept("GET", "example/API", { fixture: "fixture1.json" });
});
```

and for the 2nd run I would put:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept("GET", "example/API", { fixture: "fixture2.json" });
});
```

and so on. All my test cases are identical for different responses and I expect them to have the same result regardless of the data returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

Running a suite with different parameters

```js
cypress run --env fixture=fixture1
// or
cypress run --env fixture=fixture2
```

Ref [Environment Variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env)

In support/index.js

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  const fixtureName = `${Cypress.env('fixture')}.json`
  cy.intercept("GET", "example/API", { fixture: fixtureName });
})
```

***I expect them to have the same result regardless of the data returned by the API***  - I'm not sure what that means exactly but to me it suggests you don't have to worry about changing the fixture.

---

If you want a single call from the command line to run the whole suite, say 3 times with a different fixture each time, consider using the [Cypress Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api)

In a script file, e.g `/scripts/run-fixtures.js`

```js
const fixtures = ['fixture1.json','fixture2.json','fixture3.json']  

const cypress = require('cypress')

fixtures.forEach((fixtureName) => {

  cypress.run({
    reporter: 'junit',
    browser: 'chrome',
    config: {
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
      video: true,
    },
    env: {
      fixture: fixtureName,
    },
  })
})
```

Run it with `node /scripts/run-fixtures`.

support/index.js is the same as above.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the tests are run twice from the command line? Would it be possible to have a single cypress run command and run the tests multiple times with specified fixtures? Because I can have up to 10 fixtures.

Comment: I expect them to have the same result regardless of the data returned by the API - what I mean by this is that I expect the tests to still pass regardless of the fixture being used. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm just showing you the way to call with different env variables, don't call twice if you don't want to run twice.